# is context in BroadcastReceiver.onReceive always the activity that calls registerReceiver?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

My activity has registered a BroadcastReceiver using `registerReceiver()`. I would like to update some UI when a broadcast is received.
In my experiment I found the context happen to be my activity(singleinstance),

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(tag, context.getClass().getName());
}
```

but I am not sure if it is always the case as the docs are not clear about it.
Can I just cast the context parameter to my activity?

What would be a good practice to change activity in `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Update UI, take one  Receiver as inner class of activity and broadcast action. Now catch inside  onReceive() and update activity.
**You should unregister it after use is over**
and context is always of the activity that register broadcast as a onReceive(). You can send a broadcast from service to initiate the update if you are doing calculation in service.

Comment: On receive is _only_ called in the receiver - what you mean by "onReceive() can be called even from the service" ??

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Last line was mess up. Thanks for addressing this issue. I edited my answer

Comment: "that register broadcast as a onReceive()" ? :D I want the answer - I'd be happy to vote up once it makes sense. You mean the context is always that of the activity that registered the receiver _even when the broadcast comes from a service_ ? What about receivers registered in the manifest (not via register receiver)? Please try to express yourself clearly in English (I am not English - mind !)

Comment: Updating UI != creating new activity. The answer doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: @Sameer, now it's ok. But for me it is still unclear whether it can be done with external (not inner class) BroadcastReceiver =)